# Checked has changed into false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am a beginner I am confused about how value changed, I am attaching a screenshot of material UI switch
[image]

in this screenshot  `setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked })`in this code `event.target.checked` value is coming from

```
<Switch
        checked={state.checkedA}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="checkedA"
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }}
      />
```

`checked={state.checkedA}` is coming from state `[state, setState] =React.useState({checkedA:true,});`

how checkedA become false
I have a link here `https://codesandbox.io/s/hjvt8?file=/demo.js:344-509`
i have console these i have never use false in my code how it become false?
[image]

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous - that means if you console log straight after without awaiting (which you do not need to do), the state might not instantly reflect the changes

Comment: I don't see what the problem is in the sandbox, when I open it the switch is turned on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Switch from Material UI and it behaves like an HTML checkbox with different styling.

So the time you toggle Switch it toggles the checked value between true and false. On line 14 you get the updated checked value from Switch. if you try to toggle twice. You will see the difference it will toggle the values between true and false.

I hope it answers your question and clears the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

Among the three console statements, the last console displays "checked" not "checkedA", "checkedA" is still true.

Comment: no its false check answer below of my screenShoot

Comment: checked={state.checkedA}

Comment: as mentioned by @nbokmans setState is asynchronous hence the sequence of execution of console statements  is not as expected.